# Generating working CHM files using Doxygen and GraphViz (Invalid .hhc file?)

Tags: c++, doxygen, graphviz, dot, chm

I'm in the middle of documenting my C++ GUI library and I just started using Doxygen. I've got two test files that are documented now, but I have problems when trying to generate the CHM help files. Doxygen runs without error, and dot appears to be functioning correctly to generate images.

However, it appears the resulting .hhc, .hhk, and .hhp files are broken in some way. index.hhc and index.hhk are exactly the same and running 'hhc index.hhp' does not work. It returns an error :

HHC6000: Error: An internal file could not be created. Make certain there is enough disk space on the drive where you are compiling your file.
HHC5007: Error: Fatal navigational compilation error. This is likely the result of an invalid contents (.hhc) file.

I have uploaded a zip file of my two test sources, the Doxyfile generated by the Doxy Wizard, and the .hh* files created by doxygen.

http://members.allegro.cc/EdgarReynaldo/temp/test1.zip

Both HTML Help Workshop and GraphViz are on my path.

Do I need to change a setting in the doxyfile? How do I fix this?

Regards, bugsquasher

*EDIT*
After taking albert 's advice, everything seemed to magically work. Nothing was really different though.

Comment: I have no problems (I see that you used 1.8.15, so did I). I ran doxygen and it gave me the Eagle.chm file including graphs. I had to correct the `HHC_LOCATION` to `"C:/Program Files (x86)/HTML Help Workshop/hhc.exe"` (note the extra space between the `s` and the `(` though your path might be OK  further I used the forward slashes but this is not important). I also set `GENERATE_HTMLHELP` to `YES`. Please try to run doxygen from the command line from the directory where your Doxyfile is and report (by editing the question) also the last 10 lines that appear from the terminal window.

Comment: @albert For some reason it's working now. Voodoo. I ran doxygen from the command line after fixing the path for Html Help Workshop and it worked. It also worked to generate the CHM from the index.hhp file it created. I don't know what was different enough to fix it.

Comment: Probably it will work from the DoxyWizard as well.